# Hadoop Hive ACID query error

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

I work on an hadoop cluster, hortonworks 2.4 distribution. 
I want to make ACID operations on a Hive table. Here is my declaration statement:

```
CREATE TABLE myAcidTable (..)
CLUSTERED BY(myKey) INTO 1 BUCKETS
STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true','orc.compress'='SNAPPY');
```

I populate this table based on a external Hive table, which have the same structure.

```
INSERT INTO myAcidTable
SELECT * FROM MyTmpTable;
```

This operation works well:

> Loading data to table MyAcidTable
>   Table myAcidTable stats:
>   [numFiles=1, numRows=4450, totalSize=42001, rawDataSize=0]
>   OK

I try to query this table via hive shell:

```
set hive.support.concurrency=true;
set hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
set hive.compactor.initiator.on=true;
set hive.compactor.worker.threads=3;

SELECT * FROM myAcidTable
WHERE myKey = 12;
```

But i have this error (even if the status seems to be OK):

> OK
>   Failed with exception
>   java.io.IOException:java.lang.RuntimeException: serious problem

When I look through the logs I find this:

> org.apache.ambari.view.hive.client.HiveErrorStatusException: H170
>   Unable to fetch results. java.io.IOException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: serious problem
>
> ...
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: delta_0000000_0000000 does not
>   start with base_

It's weird because when I declare my table without the transactional propoerty, the select statement works well

```
CREATE TABLE myAcidTable (..)
CLUSTERED BY(myKey) INTO 1 BUCKETS
STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ('orc.compress'='SNAPPY');

SELECT * FROM myAcidTable
WHERE myKey = 12;
```

Results:

> OK
>   12 ...

Do you have any idea where to look? thanks for the help.

The full error:

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: java.io.IOException: 
>   java.lang.RuntimeExce
>
> ption: serious problem    at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.getNextRowSet(SQLOperation.java:352)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager.getOperationNextRowSet(OperationManager.java:223)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.fetchResults(HiveSessionImpl.java:716)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.access$000(HiveSessionProxy.java:36)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1.run(HiveSessionProxy.java:63)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:59)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.fetchResults(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.fetchResults(CLIService.java:454)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.FetchResults(ThriftCLIService.java:672)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults.getResult(TCLIService.java:1557)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults.getResult(TCLIService.java:1542)
>     at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
>     at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:285)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: serious problem  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:512)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:419)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:143)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:1737)    at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.getNextRowSet(SQLOperation.java:347)
>     ... 24 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: serious problem
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1115)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getSplits(OrcInputFormat.java:1142)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextSplits(FetchOperator.java:367)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:299)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:450)
>     ... 28 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: delta_0000000_0000000 does not
>   start with base_  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1092)
>     ... 32 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   delta_0000000_0000000 does not start with base_   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.AcidUtils.parseBase(AcidUtils.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.AcidUtils.parseBaseBucketFilename(AcidUtils.java:182)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$FileGenerator.call(OrcInputFormat.java:725)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$FileGenerator.call(OrcInputFormat.java:690)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     ... 3
>   more

Comment: Have you tried setting those values before creating the table rather than before querying?

Comment: Yes, I also change those values into the configuration file, no changes..

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you had the wrong transaction manager at the time of creating the table or loading the data into the table.

In my case, i had `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DummyTxnManager`

instead of `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager`

To get rid of the error, you need to drop the table, set the correct transaction manager i.e

`hive> set hive.txn.manager = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;`

and then re-create the table.